# How does ski wax (nonpolar liquid) dissolve into polyethylene (nonpolar plastic)?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science, physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

Ive been reading alot about ski waxing and a reputable source said that when you iron in paraffin wax into the base of a ski or snowboard, the wax melts from the heat of the iron and dissolves into the solid polyethylene base material. Is this possible for a liquid to dissolve into a solid like that?

Comment: google colloids-gels...i think in your context the wax just melts into the microscopic roughness of the ski surface

Comment: Lineage, the source i have says that the majority of the wax gets dissolved into the polyethylene rather than just filling the nooks and crannies (which at least some probably does though). 
Both polyethylene and paraffin wax are nonpolar, so i guess the liquid can move in with the solid just like molecular polyethylene might dissolve into liquid paraffin?

Comment: I googled different phrases like 20 times trying to find a single sentence that stated a liquid could be a solute that dissolves into solid solvent, but i found nothing.

Comment: FWIW, [polyethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) and pure [parafin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraffin_wax) have the same basic [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkane). The main difference is that the polyethylene molecules are much longer than the molecules in parafin.